# Create a new column for group based on condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science

I wanted to create a new column (Group ID) on the basis of following conditions:
If the DOB and first three letters of Name are same, then it must fall is same Group ID.

| Name | DOB | Group ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Anny | 18-01-1922 | 0 |
| Anny Scott | 01-01-1950 | 1 |
| Annie | 01-01-1950 | 1 |
| David | 14-02-1950 | 2 |
| David Kern | 15-02-1951 | 3 |
| William Perry | 15-02-1953 | 4 |
| Kenneth Field | 15-02-1953 | 5 |

This how I want to create the groups

I have used the following code, to create the group ID for name (If first three letters are matched)
df['Group ID Name']=df.groupby(df['name'].str[:3]).ngroup()

The following code is used to create the group ID for DOB (If two records have the same DOB)
df['Group ID DOB']=df.groupby('Date of Birth').ngroup()

I want to use both the condition to create the Group ID, please help me out for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add multiple columns in list and also for correct ordering `sort=False`:

```
df['Group ID Name'] = df.groupby(['DOB',df['Name'].str[:3]], sort=False).ngroup()
print (df)
            Name         DOB  Group;ID  Group ID Name
0           Anny  18-01-1922         0              0
1     Anny Scott  01-01-1950         1              1
2          Annie  01-01-1950         1              1
3          David  14-02-1950         2              2
4     David Kern  15-02-1951         3              3
5   William erry  15-02-1953         4              4
6  Kenneth Field  15-02-1953         5              5
```